# Removing Duplicate Values From List (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, nlp

I'm try to make an inverted index for some NLP to see how many times a word appears in a document. I'm doing this via a dictionary but my output is like this (here the word man appears in documents 1 and 11)

```
{'man': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
 'upon': [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1539, 1539, 1539]}
```

How do I get rid of these duplicate values so I just have

```
{'man': [1,11], 'upon': [1,3,1539]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order? BTW perhaps the best approach is not to create these lists with duplicates in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert values to sets and then back to lists:

```
my_dict = {k: list(set(v)) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I should have known it was something to do with sets as they don't have doubles!

Comment: Without comprehension: `dict(zip(my_dict.keys(), map(list, map(set, my_dict.values()))))`